# Why 'config' file is not created when i run 'rvm install 1.9.*'

Tags: rvm

When i install fresh instance of any ruby via rvm, and run 'rvm list', I get:

```
rvm rubies

/Users/AirBook/.rvm/scripts/list: line 321: /Users/AirBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/config: No such file or directory
ruby-1.9.2-p320 [  ]
ruby-1.9.3-p194 [  ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [  ]
```

this is not much of an issue as I just add 'config' file to specific ruby folder. Plus I do not foresee my self adding a lot of different versions of rubies.

but still wondering about this peculiar behavior, any idea what's up with it, should I be passing additional flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a problem with rvm version 1.16.17. It is already fixed on the current version (1.16.17) as you can see here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1254

You just need update rvm:

```
rvm get stable
```

or if you prefer, you can use the previous version, as well (I did this while the patch was not included on the stable version)

```
rvm get 1.16.15
```

cheers